# bootcamp install error: "windows could not parse or process the unattend file for pass [specialize]

Tags: bootcamp, windows, usb

I get the following error when installing windows on a new partition using bootcamp assistant. I'm using a 16gb usb 2.0/3.0 drive with `Win10_1709_English_x64` ISO downloaded from the Microsoft website.

Install appears to run smoothly from the Mac side. Then at a certain point, I receive the error seen here

[image: pass file error]

Then, when I select OK, the system displays the second error message which leads to a restart loop that stops at this second message. I am unable to complete the install. The first time this happened, I wiped the bootcamp partition and started over. Same thing happened again.

I read somewhere that the `unattend.xml`may be the culprit, so I backed it up and deleted it thinking the installer would recreate the file. It didn't and the install still fails.

[image: restart loop]

Here is the complete `AutoUnattend.xml` file found on the usb `root`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
      <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <WillShowUI>Always</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
            </UserData>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpCustomizationsWinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DriverPaths>
                <PathAndCredentials wcm:keyValue="1" wcm:action="add">
                    <Path>$WinPEDriver$</Path>
                </PathAndCredentials>
            </DriverPaths>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Path>cmd /c "FOR %i IN (X F E D C) DO (FOR /F "tokens=6" %t in ('vol %i:') do (IF /I %t NEQ "" (IF EXIST %i:\BootCamp\BootCamp.xml Reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v AppsRoot /t REG_SZ /d %i /f )))"</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <FirstLogonCommands>
              <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                  <Description>BootCamp setup</Description>
                  <CommandLine>%AppsRoot%:\BootCamp\setup.exe</CommandLine>
                  <Order>1</Order>
                  <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
              </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

Hopefully, someone can help me make sense of this. Thanks everyone. LMK if you need any more info.

Answer (score 2):

Just spoke with Apple Support. It appears that I'm using an upgrade-only ISO, not the full retail version. That is why it's failing. MS, in its infinite wisdom, always just assume everyone uses their OS. Big dummies.

Comment: thanks for this I have never had an issue with bootcamp before I'll try this and get back to you if it works, Where should we get the "full retail version" iso?

Comment: From what a Microsoft rep explained to me, you'll need to have your full-retail license key. You can then download it from the Microsoft website. Check your order history if you purchased the license separately rather than acquiring with a PC purchase.